# Count rows with inner joined tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables:

#### Players:

```
    mysql> SELECT * FROM players;
+-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| player_id | team_id | player_name          | player_jersey_number | player_position | player_email                 | player_contact_number | player_timestamp    |
+-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|         1 |       4 | Popoy Alfonso        |                    2 |                 | popoyalfonso@gmail.com       | 09263453234           | 2015-08-05 00:48:10 |
|         2 |       4 | Karlo Ripas          |                   10 |                 | karloripas@yahoo.com         | 09212354324           | 2015-08-05 00:50:03 |
|         3 |       4 | VHaughn Von          |                   32 |                 | von@outlook.com              | 09361234565           | 2015-08-05 00:51:00 |
|         4 |       4 | Lordie Zalbahe       |                   23 |                 | lordiezalbahe@gmail.com      | 09391222334           | 2015-08-05 00:52:42 |
|         5 |       4 | Jigs Selda           |                    8 |                 | jigsselda@gmail.com          | 09325566323           | 2015-08-05 00:53:36 |
|         6 |       4 | Rhan Garniel         |                    3 |                 | rhangarniel@ymail.com        | 09129503400           | 2015-08-05 00:54:20 |
|         7 |       5 | Johnritz Rodriguez   |                   11 |                 | johnritz@gmail.com           | 09231112346           | 2015-08-05 00:56:02 |
|         8 |       5 | Garret Van Sarmiento |                    7 |                 | garretvansarmiento@gmail.com | 09264565600           | 2015-08-05 00:56:53 |
|         9 |       5 | Lester Selda Lineses |                   12 |                 | lesterlineses@yahoo.com      | 09068746354           | 2015-08-05 00:57:47 |
|        10 |       5 | Laurence Lineses     |                   44 |                 | laurencelineses@yahoo.com    | 09847354672           | 2015-08-05 00:59:33 |
|        11 |       5 | Xandrix Buendia      |                    1 |                 | xandrixbuendia@yahoo.com     | 09234665590           | 2015-08-05 01:00:12 |
|        12 |       5 | Betoyskie Limpiada   |                   45 |                 | betoyskie@outlook.com        | 09213456667           | 2015-08-05 01:01:15 |
+-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

#### Teams:

```
    mysql> SELECT * FROM teams;
+---------+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+
| team_id | season_id | team_name            | team_timestamp      |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+
|       4 |         1 | Quiapo A             | 2015-08-05 00:30:13 |
|       5 |         1 | Quiapo B             | 2015-08-05 00:30:25 |
|       6 |         1 | Balik-Balik Warriors | 2015-08-05 00:31:13 |
|       7 |         1 | Adamson Falcons      | 2015-08-05 00:31:42 |
|       8 |         1 | Pasay Flooders       | 2015-08-05 00:32:04 |
|       9 |         1 | Marina Dragons       | 2015-08-05 00:32:22 |
|      10 |         1 | MDC Archers          | 2015-08-05 00:33:12 |
|      11 |         2 | Quiapo A             | 2015-08-05 00:34:25 |
|      12 |         2 | Quiapo B             | 2015-08-05 00:34:38 |
|      13 |         2 | Marikina Eagels      | 2015-08-05 00:35:11 |
|      14 |         2 | TIP Steallers        | 2015-08-05 00:35:32 |
|      15 |         2 | Gasan Blue Eagles    | 2015-08-05 00:36:12 |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

#### Seasons:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM seasons;
+-----------+-------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| season_id | season_name | season_event_name    | season_timestamp    |
+-----------+-------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|         1 | Season 1    | Summer Games         | 2015-08-05 00:23:15 |
|         2 | Season 2    | Aniversary Sportfest | 2015-08-05 00:25:10 |
+-----------+-------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

I'm currently working on this query but the result is not correct.

```
SELECT 
    teams.team_name,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM teams 
        INNER JOIN players 
            ON teams.team_id = players.team_id
    ) as num_of_players, 
    teams.team_timestamp
FROM teams 
INNER JOIN seasons 
    ON seasons.season_id = teams.season_id 
GROUP BY teams.team_name;
```

#### Output:

```
+----------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| team_name            | num_of_players | team_timestamp      |
+----------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| Adamson Falcons      |             12 | 2015-08-05 00:31:42 |
| Balik-Balik Warriors |             12 | 2015-08-05 00:31:13 |
| Gasan Blue Eagles    |             12 | 2015-08-05 00:36:12 |
| Marikina Eagels      |             12 | 2015-08-05 00:35:11 |
| Marina Dragons       |             12 | 2015-08-05 00:32:22 |
| MDC Archers          |             12 | 2015-08-05 00:33:12 |
| Pasay Flooders       |             12 | 2015-08-05 00:32:04 |
| Quiapo A             |             12 | 2015-08-05 00:30:13 |
| Quiapo B             |             12 | 2015-08-05 00:30:25 |
| TIP Steallers        |             12 | 2015-08-05 00:35:32 |
+----------------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

#### The result that I want is this:

```
+----------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| team_name            | num_of_players | team_timestamp      |
+----------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| Adamson Falcons      |              0 | 2015-08-05 00:31:42 |
| Balik-Balik Warriors |              0 | 2015-08-05 00:31:13 |
| Gasan Blue Eagles    |              0 | 2015-08-05 00:36:12 |
| Marikina Eagels      |              0 | 2015-08-05 00:35:11 |
| Marina Dragons       |              0 | 2015-08-05 00:32:22 |
| MDC Archers          |              0 | 2015-08-05 00:33:12 |
| Pasay Flooders       |              0 | 2015-08-05 00:32:04 |
| Quiapo A             |              6 | 2015-08-05 00:30:13 |
| Quiapo B             |              6 | 2015-08-05 00:30:25 |
| TIP Steallers        |              0 | 2015-08-05 00:35:32 |
+----------------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to count? And why isn't there a proper `teams` table? (Proper meaning a table where the `team_id` and/or the `team_name` is the unique/primary key). What you call "teams" is actually a "teams-seasons" table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely rearranged answer.

I've added some data to the player and team tables to make the answers more general - see bottom of post for all DDL (`CREATE TABLE tab_name...`) and DML (`INSERT INTO tab_name VALUES...`) used in this answer. I also created the season table (unchanged from the OP's - i.e. your) original data.

BTW, welcome to the forum. But you should really have given us the DDL and DML. Take a look at the tour and also the "how to help us to help you" blog - both at the bottom left of the page. But, I got interested and did it myself, but you will get more people to help you if you provide DDL and DML.

After creating and loading the tables, I ran the following SQL.

```
SELECT t1.team_name,
       IFNULL(t2.num_players, 0) AS strength,
       t1.team_timestamp
FROM team t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT team_id, COUNT(team_id) AS num_players 
     FROM player 
     GROUP BY team_id
    ) t2
ON t1.team_id = t2.team_id
-- GROUP BY t1.team_id, t1.team_name, t1.season_id  -- **NOTE** - see discussion below
ORDER BY strength DESC, team_name ASC;
```

And the result is not quite the one you want, but close.

```
+----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| team_name            | strength | team_timestamp      |
+----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| Quiapo B             |        7 | 2015-08-05 00:30:25 |
| Quiapo B             |        7 | 2015-08-05 00:30:25 |
| Quiapo A             |        6 | 2015-08-05 00:30:13 |
| Quiapo A             |        6 | 2015-08-05 00:30:13 |
| Adamson Falcons      |        0 | 2015-08-05 00:31:42 |
| Balik-Balik Warriors |        0 | 2015-08-05 00:31:13 |
| Gasan Blue Eagles    |        0 | 2015-08-05 00:36:12 |
| Marikina Eagels      |        0 | 2015-08-05 00:35:11 |
| Marina Dragons       |        0 | 2015-08-05 00:32:22 |
| MDC Archers          |        0 | 2015-08-05 00:33:12 |
| Pasay Flooders       |        0 | 2015-08-05 00:32:04 |
| TIP Steallers        |        0 | 2015-08-05 00:35:32 |
+----------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

Running oNare's query gives (!)

```
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+
| team_name | num_of_players | team_timestamp      |
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+
| Quiapo A  |             26 | 2015-08-05 00:30:13 |
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Note that 26 = 2 * (6 + 7). But, if `sql_mode` is set to `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, this query will fail with the message

```
ERROR 1140 (42000): Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

However, a slight modification of oNare's query gives the same results as I obtained with my first query (with sql_mode not set to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`).

```
SELECT 
team.team_name, 
COUNT(player.player_id) as num_of_players,
team.team_timestamp
FROM team 
LEFT JOIN player ON (player.team_id = team.team_id)
LEFT JOIN seasons ON (seasons.season_id = team.season_id) 
GROUP BY team.team_name, team.season_id, team.team_timestamp -- **ADDED**
ORDER BY num_of_players DESC, team.team_name ASC;
```

Adding the GROUP BY gives the correct answer. It is interesting to note that PostgreSQL will throw an error if the `GROUP BY` line is commented out. My query won't work either on PostgreSQL if I don't add a `GROUP BY` line immediately before the `ORDER BY` line.

I think as a general answer, you could accept either of our answers as correct for your question (with `GROUP BY`) - it's not possible to obtain your desired results without more information in the tables, but see below.

As an aside, `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` will be the [default mode for 5.7](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-only_full_group_by-improved-recognizing-functional-dependencies-enabled-by-default/), so might as well get it right now!

I think that your table structure needs some revision. You should have players for different seasons (makes sense, people transfer). You should have the same `id`s for the same team over different seasons - otherwise how are you going to aggregate statistics (goals/points/matches-won/lost) over many seasons?

## **TABLE DDL and DML - STRUCTURE and CONTENTS.**

```
CREATE TABLE player (player_id INT, team_id INT, player_name VARCHAR(25));
CREATE TABLE team( team_id INT, season_id INT, team_name VARCHAR(25), team_timestamp TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE season (season_id INT, season_name VARCHAR(25));

INSERT INTO player VALUES (1, 4, 'Popoy Alfonso'); 
INSERT INTO player VALUES (2, 4, 'Karlo Ripas');
INSERT INTO player VALUES (3, 4, 'VHaughn Von');
INSERT INTO player VALUES (4, 4, 'Lordie Zalbahe');
INSERT INTO player VALUES (5, 4, 'Jigs Selda'          );
INSERT INTO player VALUES (6, 4, 'Rhan Garniel'        );
INSERT INTO player VALUES (7, 5, 'Johnritz Rodriguez'  );
INSERT INTO player VALUES (8, 5, 'Garret Van Sarmiento');
INSERT INTO player VALUES (9, 5, 'Lester Selda Lineses');
INSERT INTO player VALUES (10, 5,  'Laurence Lineses'    );
INSERT INTO player VALUES (11, 5,  'Xandrix Buendia'      );
INSERT INTO player VALUES (12, 5, 'Betoyskie Limpiada'   );
INSERT INTO player VALUES (12, 5, 'Donald Duck'   );  -- Added Donald Duck!

-- I inserted extra records into the player table as below.

INSERT INTO player VALUES (1, 11, 'Popoy Alfonso'); 
INSERT INTO player VALUES (2, 11, 'Karlo Ripas');
INSERT INTO player VALUES (3, 11, 'VHaughn Von');
INSERT INTO player VALUES (11, 11, 'Lordie Zalbahe');
INSERT INTO player VALUES (5, 11, 'Jigs Selda'          );
INSERT INTO player VALUES (6, 11, 'Rhan Garniel'        );
INSERT INTO player VALUES (7, 12, 'Johnritz Rodriguez'  );
INSERT INTO player VALUES (8, 12, 'Garret Van Sarmiento');
INSERT INTO player VALUES (9, 12, 'Lester Selda Lineses');
INSERT INTO player VALUES (10, 12,  'Laurence Lineses'    );
INSERT INTO player VALUES (11, 12,  'Xandrix Buendia'      );
INSERT INTO player VALUES (12, 12, 'Betoyskie Limpiada'   );
```

For the team table, I gave QuiradoA and QuiradoB the same `id` in season 1 and season 2 - it makes no sense to me to have different `id`s for the same team just because the season changes. I also retained the same `TIMESTAMP` for QuiradoA and B.

```
INSERT INTO team VALUES (   4 ,         1 , 'Quiapo A'             , '2015-08-05 00:30:13');
INSERT INTO team VALUES (   5 ,         1 , 'Quiapo B'             , '2015-08-05 00:30:25');
INSERT INTO team VALUES (   6 ,         1 , 'Balik-Balik Warriors' , '2015-08-05 00:31:13');
INSERT INTO team VALUES (   7 ,         1 , 'Adamson Falcons'      , '2015-08-05 00:31:42');
INSERT INTO team VALUES (   8 ,         1 , 'Pasay Flooders'       , '2015-08-05 00:32:04');
INSERT INTO team VALUES (   9 ,         1 , 'Marina Dragons'       , '2015-08-05 00:32:22');
INSERT INTO team VALUES (  10 ,         1 , 'MDC Archers'          , '2015-08-05 00:33:12');
INSERT INTO team VALUES (   4 ,         2 , 'Quiapo A'             , '2015-08-05 00:30:13'); -- **NOTE** `id` and `TIMESTAMP` for both A & B.
INSERT INTO team VALUES (   5 ,         2 , 'Quiapo B'             , '2015-08-05 00:30:25');
INSERT INTO team VALUES (  13 ,         2 , 'Marikina Eagels'      , '2015-08-05 00:35:11');
INSERT INTO team VALUES (  14 ,         2 , 'TIP Steallers'        , '2015-08-05 00:35:32');
INSERT INTO team VALUES (  15 ,         2 , 'Gasan Blue Eagles'    , '2015-08-05 00:36:12');



INSERT INTO season VALUES(1, 'Season 1');
INSERT INTO season VALUES(2, 'Season 2');
```

Comment: "You shouldn't use plural names for tables"....a few paragraphs later "I was interested in onares different approach, so I created a seasons table".  Make up your mind do you recommend the plural table names or not?

Comment: @JonH - I was having enough trouble running queries on different servers and I wanted to have to modify oNane's queries as little as possible, so I used the plural. I would not normally do so. Apologies if you were discommoded.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is giving you 12 `num_of_players` because your counting just the subquery returned rows, if you run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teams INNER JOIN players ON teams.team_id = players.team_id;` you will see what you're really doing.

To fix your syntax just one more `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    teams.team_name, 
    COUNT(players.player_id) as num_of_players, 
    teams.team_timestamp
FROM test.teams 
LEFT JOIN test.players ON (players.team_id=teams.team_id)
LEFT JOIN test.seasons ON (seasons.season_id = teams.season_id) 
GROUP BY teams.team_name;
```

**Test info:**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.players;
+-----------+---------+--------------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------+------------------+
| player_id | team_id | player_name        | player_jersey_number | player_position | player_email | player_contact_number | player_timestamp |
+-----------+---------+--------------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------+------------------+
|         1 | 4       | Popoy Alfonso      | 2                    | NULL            | NULL         | NULL                  | NULL             |
|         2 | 4       | NULL               | 10                   | NULL            | NULL         | NULL                  | NULL             |
|         3 | 4       | NULL               | NULL                 | NULL            | NULL         | NULL                  | NULL             |
|         4 | 4       | NULL               | NULL                 | NULL            | NULL         | NULL                  | NULL             |
|         5 | 4       | NULL               | NULL                 | NULL            | NULL         | NULL                  | NULL             |
|         6 | 4       | NULL               | NULL                 | NULL            | NULL         | NULL                  | NULL             |
|         7 | 5       | Johnritz Rodriguez | 11                   | NULL            | NULL         | NULL                  | NULL             |
|         8 | 5       | NULL               | NULL                 | NULL            | NULL         | NULL                  | NULL             |
|         9 | 5       | NULL               | NULL                 | NULL            | NULL         | NULL                  | NULL             |
|        10 | 5       | NULL               | NULL                 | NULL            | NULL         | NULL                  | NULL             |
|        11 | 5       | NULL               | NULL                 | NULL            | NULL         | NULL                  | NULL             |
|        12 | 5       | NULL               | NULL                 | NULL            | NULL         | NULL                  | NULL             |
+-----------+---------+--------------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------+------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test.teams;
+---------+-----------+----------------------+----------------+
| team_id | season_id | team_name            | team_timestamp |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+----------------+
|       4 | 1         | Quiapo A             | NULL           |
|       5 | 1         | Quiapo B             | NULL           |
|       6 | 1         | Balik-Balik Warriors | NULL           |
|       7 | 1         | Adamson Falcons      | NULL           |
|       8 | 1         | Pasay Flooders       | NULL           |
|       9 | 1         | Marina Dragons       | NULL           |
|      10 | 1         | MDC Archers          | NULL           |
|      11 | 2         | Quiapo A             | NULL           |
|      12 | 2         | Quiapo B             | NULL           |
|      13 | 2         | Marikina Eagels      | NULL           |
|      14 | 2         | TIP Steallers        | NULL           |
|      15 | 2         | Gasan Blue Eagles    | NULL           |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test.seasons;
+-----------+-------------+----------------------+------------------+
| season_id | season_name | season_event_name    | season_timestamp |
+-----------+-------------+----------------------+------------------+
|         1 | Season 1    | Summer Games         | NULL             |
|         2 | Season 2    | Aniversary Sportfest | NULL             |
+-----------+-------------+----------------------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**Your QUERY:**

```
mysql> SELECT teams.team_name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teams INNER JOIN players ON teams.team_id = players.team_id) as num_of_players, teams.team_timestamp
    -> FROM teams 
    -> INNER JOIN seasons 
    -> ON seasons.season_id = teams.season_id 
    -> GROUP BY teams.team_name;
+----------------------+----------------+----------------+
| team_name            | num_of_players | team_timestamp |
+----------------------+----------------+----------------+
| Adamson Falcons      |             12 | NULL           |
| Balik-Balik Warriors |             12 | NULL           |
| Gasan Blue Eagles    |             12 | NULL           |
| Marikina Eagels      |             12 | NULL           |
| Marina Dragons       |             12 | NULL           |
| MDC Archers          |             12 | NULL           |
| Pasay Flooders       |             12 | NULL           |
| Quiapo A             |             12 | NULL           |
| Quiapo B             |             12 | NULL           |
| TIP Steallers        |             12 | NULL           |
+----------------------+----------------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**Fixed QUERY:**

```
mysql> SELECT 
    ->     teams.team_name, 
    ->     COUNT(players.player_id) as num_of_players, 
    ->     teams.team_timestamp
    -> FROM test.teams 
    -> LEFT JOIN test.players ON (players.team_id=teams.team_id)
    -> LEFT JOIN test.seasons ON (seasons.season_id = teams.season_id) 
    -> GROUP BY teams.team_name;
+----------------------+----------------+----------------+
| team_name            | num_of_players | team_timestamp |
+----------------------+----------------+----------------+
| Adamson Falcons      |              0 | NULL           |
| Balik-Balik Warriors |              0 | NULL           |
| Gasan Blue Eagles    |              0 | NULL           |
| Marikina Eagels      |              0 | NULL           |
| Marina Dragons       |              0 | NULL           |
| MDC Archers          |              0 | NULL           |
| Pasay Flooders       |              0 | NULL           |
| Quiapo A             |              6 | NULL           |
| Quiapo B             |              6 | NULL           |
| TIP Steallers        |              0 | NULL           |
+----------------------+----------------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

See the output here: [**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba70a/2)

Comment: @All: You might find it more convenient to [continue this interesting discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26924/discussion-on-answer-by-onare-count-rows-with-inner-joined-tables).